# PHP Curl upload image, on IIS 7, image not completely uploaded

Tags: php, rest, iis-7, curl, image-uploading

I have a html form which contains a file upload. When the form is sent, I re-send it with curl. My REST API receive the request and when I check for `$_FILES['image']['error']` it gives me 3 which is  'Only part of the file was uploaded'. I used to upload images on my site with no problems before the REST service.

Obviously I tested it on localhost but I was using apache and it worked just fine.

Now I am on IIS 7. I checked the curl lib for iis, and the request is sent with no problem...

Looking for an IIS config or code to fix this...

```
$header = array("Content-type: multipart/form-data");

$tmpfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];

$data = array(
            'image' => '@' . $tmpfile . ';filename='.$filename.';type='.$type.';size='.$size.';' );

 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
 $this->doExecute($ch);
```

edit: doesn't seem like a file too big problem, can't upload a 600 bytes jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! so it was a folder permission problem. for some unknown reasons, file upload was working just fine before the service implementation.......

So I edited the default upload folder which is C:\Windows\Temp and I added full control permission for iis_iusrs .

thanks